# Pause android YouTubePlayer right after video has started

Tags: android, youtube

I want to load a video and set the player to paused state.

I'm doing it like this:

```java
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.provider provider, final YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    player.loadVideo("dfsafas");
    player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new PlayerStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {
            player.pause();
        }
        //...
    });
}
```

The problem is: It doesn't work 8-). This means the video is just played as soon as its loaded. When I add a little delay e.g. `Thread.sleep(5000);`, the Video is paused correctly.

Why is the video not stopped as soon as it is started when I call `pause` in the `PlayerStateChangeListener`s `onVideoStarted` or `onVideoLoaded` callback?

Comment: Have you got any solution for this

Answer (score 2):

For me, what worked was:

```
player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {
        ...

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String s) {
            player.pause();
        }

        ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
player.setPlaybackEventListener(new PlaybackEventListener() {

    private boolean interceptPlay = true;

    @Override
    public void onPlaying() {
        if (interceptPlay) {
            player.pause();
            interceptPlay = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopped() {}

    @Override
    public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void onPaused() {}

    @Override
    public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

onVideoStarted gets called when ever the player start playing video.

If you try to pause the video at first line of onVideoStarted it will stop as soon as started.

Try to pause at another event.

can be on a button or something else.

Comment: I want it to "stop as soon as started". And no, it is not stopping as soon as it is started, which is the problem I am trying to solve here.

Comment: Try using PlayerStateChangeListener and inside onVideoStarted() try to pause this should work.